# '404 Not Found. The requested url / was not found on this server' Django deployment with apache2

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, apache2, django-deployment

I'm developing a django website and am currently working on deploying. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds&t=4080s) tutorial. And im in the last stage of the tutorial (1:08:00 in the video). After he finished configuration th django-project.conf file he saves and everything is working, but me on the other hand, i get an:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu) Server at **** Port 80

This is my projects .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _
    Redirect 404 /
    Alias /static /home/user/project/static
    <Directory /home/user/project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/user/project/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/project/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess project_app python-path=/home/user/project python-home=/home/user/project/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup project_app
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.homepage),
    path('rh/', views.rh, name="rh"),
    path('gvt/', views.gvt, name="gvt"),
    path('fth/', views.fth, name="fth"),
    path('pages/', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

This is my `wsgi.py`

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'excelsite.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()

sys.path.append('/home/alexholst/excelsite')
```

This is the `error.log`
(Couldnt copy, so i have this screenshot instead)
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I63hp.png)

Comment: why you are using Redirect 404 / ? in conf. file?

Comment: its something that was in the file from the beginning

Comment: I never put that in, should i take it out?

Comment: remove it and try

Comment: it gives a 500 server error now

Comment: see the error log

Comment: it shows the same error log as the pic that i linked in the post

Comment: change the debug to true and see what is the error

Comment: i changed it to true and it doesnt give any more info. Just Server Error (500)

Comment: sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log , check the output

Comment: still the same as before

Comment: we are getting somewhere tho

Comment: if i type http://example.com/admin it works so i think it might be an error with my urls.py

Comment: sorry, i didnt save the file when doing debug = true. The error is TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Comment: ok, add the template

Comment: i already have the template